# Как изменить цвет password toggle в TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Мне нужно изменить цвет password toggle в TextInputLayout если EditText в фокусе или нет. Я сделал это таким способом, но это не работает, цвет не меняется при смене фокуса, всегда равен color light grey (из state focused = false)

layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle_selector"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/color_password_toggle">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

color_password_toggle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/color_green" android:state_checked="true"  />
    <item android:color="@color/color_grey" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/color_light_grey" android:state_focused="false" />
```

password_toggle_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye" android:state_checked="true />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_off" />
```